# GAE Memory Leaks when writing to Cloud Storage, can I stream instead?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memory-leaks, google-cloud-storage

I'm requesting data from an external API, and am writing it directly to a Cloud Storage file.  The data writes just fine, but when I scale, I'm running into memory issues and hitting the 1024 MB limit on the GAE instances.

These are the critical errors I get:

```
Exceeded soft private memory limit of 1024 MB with 1425 MB after servicing 46 requests total
```

This is a summary of the code I am using:

```
import cloudstorage as gcs
import urllib2

# Example file path
filePath = '/bucket/dir/file.gzip'

def deferrableTask(filePath, api_url, post_body):
  with gcs.open(filePath, 'w') as f:
      request = urllib2.Request(api_url, post_body)
      try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout = 600)
      except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        raise customError(e)
      else:
        while True:
          chunk = response.read(16 * 1024)
          if not chunk: break
          f.write(chunk)
      f.close()
      del f
  gc.collect()
```

The task above is made to be deferrable using taskqueues.  There could be up to 40 of them running concurrently in a queue.  In my `app.yaml`, I have the following settings:

```yaml
    instance_class: F4_1G
    automatic_scaling:
      max_concurrent_requests: 4
```

This code works for writing api data to cloud storage.  It's when I start doing several hundred of these requests that I start to run into memory problems.

The gzip files requested range in size from 300 kb to 10-20 Mb, and I thought that by using `gc.collect()`, in combination with limiting the number of concurrent instance requests, would be enough to cut back on memory leaks.  I am also aware that urllib2 is only a wrapper for app engine's urlfetch, but the fetching isn't the problem, it's the scaling.

How much memory does variable `f` take up?  Is it possible to stream directly to Google Cloud Storage, rather than loading the data to instance memory first?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Our web-app is trying to `write` a file to GCS which is only 20 MB and the request fails quite frequently with the error: `Exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 MB with 216 MB after servicing 0 requests total`.

Comment: I am not using any kind of scaling. I am also not using F4_1G machines, I am using the default F1s. I don't think this problem has anything to do with instance classes or scaling settings. I am getting the memory errors on a single F1 instance, after attempting only 1 request. There must be something wrong with the `cloudstorage` lib?

Comment: I think that's the case.  Even with the forced garbage collection the instances are retaining too much of the task to memory, which leads me to believe that there is something wrong with App Engine itself.  The only work around was to send the failed tasks to a repeat queue to try again later, but even then some larger tasks would still never finish.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Jabberwockey. In your case, you were already using the best instance class available so you could not increase the memory anymore. We were only using F1s so I have changed our project to use F4s (512MB). It has been running solid for a day with no errors. Memory does occasionally spike up but eventually falls back down again.

Comment: I am having same problem too. I had to deploy server keys to dozens of media servers for direct uploading sound files to gcs. Direct upload decreased memory errors. But for some cases, i can't use direct upload method. I could not find any solution for this leak.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, that you can directly write the data to the GCS from External app, for this you have to change the ACL of the bucket to public and then with the help of the Cloud storage API write data to the bucket.

Also, let me know did you miss any details of Automatic scaling configuration in your question. If yes then please specify those details.

Comment: The data is confidential and proprietary, meaning the bucket can never be made public.